# Xamarin Shared Project - MP3 Streaming

Tags: xamarin

I am writing a simple streaming mp3 player in a Xamarin shared project. I have [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/StreamingAudio/) solution which works perfectly with iOS. I can also use the [media player solution](http://blog.xamarin.com/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin.android/) for Android (i guess) to achieve the same. Any recommendation on doing this the right way so that maximum code is shared? As i understand, i have the below options

1. Write an abstract class with the basic audio features like streaming, buffering etc in shared and then implement them in platform specific
2. Create user controls in each platform specific solution
3. Write a Portable Class Library

I have gone through [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/), but not sure which is the most sensible way to proceed given my requirement and what i have in hand.

Comment: We have something similar, a mp3 streaming solution for wp8, Android and iOS. We ended up creating an interface that is implemented in all of those platforms. We use MvvmCross to connect those platform specific instances to our Core project. Would it be helpful to share the interface with you?

Comment: Yes please, it will be very helpful. I haven't used MvvmCross before. Based on your experience, any issues?

Comment: I think MvvmCross works great. There have been some issue's with for example Fragments, but nothing that can't be worked around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this as th interface for the mediaplayer:

```
public delegate void StatusChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public delegate void CoverReloadedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public delegate void PlayingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public delegate void BufferingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

/// <summary>
/// The main purpose of this class is to be a controlling unit for all the single MediaItem implementations, who
/// in themselve can play their media, but need a central controling unit, surrounding them
/// </summary>
public interface IMediaPlayer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reading the current status of the player (STOPPED, PAUSED, PLAYING, LOADING - initialization and buffering is combined here)
    /// </summary>
    PlayerStatus Status { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when the status changes (playing, pause, buffering)
    /// </summary>
    event StatusChangedEventHandler StatusChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when the cover on the player changes
    /// </summary>
    event CoverReloadedEventHandler CoverReloaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised at least every second when the player is playing.
    /// </summary>
    event PlayingEventHandler Playing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised each time the buffering is updated by the player.
    /// </summary>
    event BufferingEventHandler Buffering;

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts playing from the current position
    /// </summary>
    Task Play();

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops playing
    /// </summary>
    Task Stop();

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops playing but retains position
    /// </summary>
    Task Pause();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the players position in milliseconds
    /// </summary>
    int Position { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the source duration in milliseconds
    /// If the response is -1, the duration is unknown or the player is still buffering.
    /// </summary>
    int Duration { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the buffered time in milliseconds
    /// </summary>
    int Buffered { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current cover. The class for the instance depends on the platform.
    /// Returns NULL if unknown.
    /// </summary>
    object Cover { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes position to the specified number of milliseconds from zero
    /// </summary>
    Task Seek(int position);

    /// <summary>
    /// Should be the same as calling PlayByPosition(Queue.size()+1)
    /// Maybe you'll want to preload the next song into memory ...
    /// </summary>
    Task PlayNext();

    /// <summary>
    /// Start playing if nothing is playing, otherwise it pauses the current media
    /// </summary>
    Task PlayPause();

    /// <summary>
    /// Should be the same as calling PlayByPosition(Queue.size()-1).
    /// Maybe you'll want to keep the last song in memory ...
    /// </summary>
    Task PlayPrevious();

    /// <summary>
    /// Start playing a track by its position in the Queue
    /// </summary>
    Task PlayByPosition(int index);
}
```

Also i have a custom queue which could be helpful to you:

```
public interface IQueue : ICollection<Track>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Activates or deactivates the Repeat option
    /// </summary>
    bool Repeat { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Activates or deactivates the Shuffle option
    /// </summary>
    bool Shuffle { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the Queue has a next track
    /// </summary>
    bool HasNext();

    /// <summary>
    /// If the Queue has a previous track
    /// </summary>
    bool HasPrevious();

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current track from the Queue
    /// </summary>
    Track Current { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current playing index the Queue
    /// </summary>
    int Index { get; }

    void setPreviousAsCurrent();

    void setNextAsCurrent();

    void setIndexAsCurrent(int index);

    void AddRange(IEnumerable<Track> items);
}
```

The playerstatus for me are:

```
public enum PlayerStatus
{
    STOPPED,
    PAUSED,
    PLAYING,
    LOADING
}
```